# Merging several XML files and grouping/sorting the results based on an attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several XML files with different structures that I would like to merge in form of a timeline based on a common attribute indicating a date (`@when`).

### file1. xml

```
<persons>

<person id="p0001">
<name>John Skelton</name>
<born when="1782-05-01">John Skelton born</born>
<died when="1866-01-05">John Skelton died</died>
</person>

...

</persons>
```

### file2.xml

```
<events>

<event id="e0001" when="1782">
<name>Publication of <hi>Transactions</hi></name>
</event>

<event id="e0002" when="1866">
<name>Boston meeting of Generals</name>
</event>

...

</events>
```

There may be several more of these XML files.

My desired output would be something along the lines of:

```
<div id="timeline">

<div class="year">1782</div>
<p data-when="1782-05-01" data-id="p0001">John Skelton born</p>
<p data-when="1782" data-id="e0001">Publication of <em>Transactions</em></p>

<div class="year">1866</div>
<p data-when="1866-01-05" data-id="p0001">John Skelton died</p>
<p data-when="1866" data-id="e0002">Boston meeting of Generals</p>

</div>
```

Is there a way of achieving this in XSLT2 that would:

1. allow for future additional files to be included,
2. make it possible to pull in further elements that have a `@when` attribute,
3. and takes into account that the items are not already sorted by date in the XML files?

I'm not too worried about the actual formatting of the output, but I'm struggling to figure out the (a) merging, (b) grouping, and (c) sorting steps that would be involved to get there in the first place.  I've experimented with grouping the documents

```
<xsl:param name="lookup-documents" select="document('file1.xml'),document('file2.xml')"/>
```

and then using a `dates` key based on the `@when` in a for-each loop, but I may be completely on the wrong track and have no XSLT to show really.

If at all possible, I'd prefer a "pull" XSLT2 solution.  Thanks very much for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to pull in the files as a collection and then use `for-each-group` to group and sort by the year, then I would push the group population to templates, to account for the different structure of elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="input-pattern" as="xs:string" select="'file*.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="input-docs" select="collection(concat('.?select=', $input-pattern))"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <div>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$input-docs//*[@when]" group-by="xs:integer(substring(@when, 1, 4))">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"></xsl:sort>
                <div class="year">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="@when"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="born | died">
        <p data-when="{@when}" data-id="{../@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="event">
        <p data-when="{@when}" data-id="{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name/node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hi">
        <em>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </em>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way I get

```
<div>
   <div class="year">1782</div>
   <p data-when="1782" data-id="e0001">Publication of <em>Transactions</em></p>
   <p data-when="1782-05-01" data-id="p0001">John Skelton born</p>
   <div class="year">1866</div>
   <p data-when="1866" data-id="e0002">Boston meeting of Generals</p>
   <p data-when="1866-01-05" data-id="p0001">John Skelton died</p>
</div>
```

you will need to change the sort of the group items I guess, it is not clear how you determine whether an item with a full date ends up before a item with only a year in `@when`.

And that collection approach is Saxon specific (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/sourcedocs/collections.html) but I think Altova and XmlPrime have similar URI collection syntax to allow to read in a number of files from a pattern.

Comment: That looks like an excellent approach.  I'm not familiar with the collection option, my files are actually spread out in different directories on different levels, could I list them individually with their appropriate paths in a way that would still work with your solution?

Comment: Sure, you could set up that variable as e.g. `<xsl:variable name="input-docs" select="doc('dir1/file1.xml'), doc('dir2/file2.xml), doc('file3.xml), doc(...)"/>` or use the parameter you have defined (`lookup-documents`) in the `xsl:for-each-group select="$lookup-documents//*[@when]"`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The sorting issue you mention I assume has to do with sorting by number vs string, is that the reason?  I'd like to avoid hacks like using "1782-99-99" to achieve the right order.  Or presumably, I could group the items that have just a year and the ones that have a fully qualified date in a different container element, but that might overcomplicate things...

Comment: No, I don't think with that format `yyyy(-mm-dd)` it is a problem of number versus string sorting, rather I couldn't find a clear description in your question as to how to sort the values once grouped by year, it is not clear how to sort e.g. 2016 versus 2016-04-02. If you explain what determines the order in that case I am sure the `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"><xsl:sort select="@when"/></xsl:apply-templates>` can be refined or rewritten to implement the requirement.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I should have thought this through properly before asking.  Ideally, items would be grouped by year initially (yyyy), then by month yyyy-mm (e.g. all January events) and then when available by day yyyy-mm-dd (01-31) in ascending order, followed by items that have just got a year. Dates will have these three options: yyyy, yyyy-mm, or yyyy-mm-dd. In each case the most precise date should come first. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you want to additionally group by month then add an inner `for-each-group` for that if you want some wrapper div for each month. And the inner sorting could for instance be changed to `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"><xsl:sort select="string-length(@when) eq 4"/><xsl:sort select="@when"/></xsl:apply-templates>` to move the `yyyy` items to the end. Just try to adapt the posted code as needed, if you don't get it done yourself then please edit the question and provide some more detailed input samples and the required output so that we have some data to test with.